# Create a window in qt with shape from an image

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Can some one explain me how to make a window in qt according to the shape of some object in an image , for example i have an image of a tree , using that i need to create a window in the shape of a tree ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[After a long search , myself found a good solution , check out this ..](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=145&key=QMainWindowPartialTransparent)

```
#include <QtGui>
 class  myMainWindow:public QMainWindow
 {
 public:
     myMainWindow():QMainWindow()
     {
    setMask((new QPixmap("saturn.png"))->mask());


    QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
    palette->setBrush(QPalette::Background,QBrush(QPixmap("saturn.png")));
    setPalette(*palette);   

    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);     
    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();

    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("Button 1");
    button1->setFixedSize(80,50);

    layout->addWidget(button1,0,0); 

    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

     };
     ~myMainWindow(){};
 };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    myMainWindow *window = new myMainWindow();    

    window->resize(600, 316);          
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Nice! For other similar things: See the clock example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock-shapedclock-cpp.html
For PySide it's here: http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/ce9b2dfe456f38a166314dc2807a6b27cd944127/examples/widgets/shapedclock.py
Simple example for splash screens:
`self.img_Check = QPixmap("resources/some_transparent_image.png")  
  self.lab = QSplashScreen(self.img_Check)
  self.lab.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
  self.lab.setMask(self.img_Check.mask())
  self.lab.setPixmap(self.img_Check)
  self.lab.show()`

Comment: Doesn't it leak `QPixmap` on each construction?

Comment: @Ruslan yeah, but mainwindow is created only once in most qt apps

Comment: This is true, but I'd suppose it's just cleaner (both syntactically and semantically) to use `QPixmap("saturn.png").mask()` instead of explicitly leaking the pixmap.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QWidget_Semi-transparent_Background_Color) is a recipe for making a widget with a semi-transparent background colour. Just expand from there by making the background fully transparent, then display the tree image on top of that as a background image. Note that the widget will still behave like a rectangular widget in regards to laying out its child elements, so you probably need to deal with this using some custom layout inside the tree shape.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the docs for `QWidget::setMask`. It has a version which takes a QBitmap and one that takes a QRegion. This is the fundamental function in getting a transparent widget. The toolkit also includes a clock example using the QRegion version -- I suspect a bitmap is just as easy though.